# Проблема со статическими файлами при установке на хотсинг проекта на django

Tags: python, django, hosting

Выполняю установку проекта на django на хостинг pythonanywhere, но не работает css также, как работал на локальной машине. Понимаю, что проблема скорее всего заключается в неправильной работе со статическими файлами.
Проект имеет структуру, в которой для каждого приложения своя отдельная папка static.
В settings.py код следующий:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: На вкладке web есть раздел static files, там указаны пути до статики?